# OpenJPA exception in ServiceMix environment

Tags: apache-camel, cxf, openjpa, apache-servicemix

ServiceMix, Camel, CXF
I wrote some database manipulate procedure what use JPA. These are not so complex. They work correctly, and I wrote a process, what use some of them.
The process "starter" is a file-based Camel route, and everything is perfect.
Ok, lets the starter a WebService. No problem, we use ServiceMix, lets do it with CXF. It is simple and we have an integrated environment, what could be the problem. 
WS ready, call the procedure and... I'v got an exception:

```
<openjpa-2.3.0-r422266:1540826 nonfatal user error> 
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: An error occurred while parsing the query filter 
"select i from IntegratedSystem i where i.code = :value". 
Error message: The name "IntegratedSystem" is not a recognized entity or identifier. 
Perhaps you meant IntegratedSystem, which is a close match. 
Known entity names: [Category, EsbLog, Message, MsgDispatcherCfg, 
ConsumerRequest, ProviderResponse, ServiceRegistry, ConsumerResponse, 
IntegratedSystem, ProviderRequest, CategoryItem]
```

It is very interesting, because the excepted entity and the close match is same.
The question:

If I call a procedure from Camel route then JPA work correctly, if I call from WS implementation, the JPA doesn't know the entity. Do you have any idea?

(The WS and the Camel route is the same project (and same package), and if I replaced the JPA select with native select then it works correctly. This is not good solution, because I use more then one selection, and I use the potential of the JPA.)

Thank you!
Feri

Answer (score 0):

```
I had similar issue, and the cause was openjpa enhancer plugin within maven could not enhance the object as it could not find persistence.xml 
and required change as:

        <enforcePropertyRestrictions>true</enforcePropertyRestrictions>
        <persistenceXmlFile>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml</persistenceXmlFile>
        <classes>${project.build.outputDirectory}</classes>
        <workDir>${project.build.directory}\openjpa-work</workDir>


Full plugin description:

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
    <artifactId>openjpa-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <includes>**/model/**/*.class</includes>
        <addDefaultConstructor>true</addDefaultConstructor>
        <enforcePropertyRestrictions>true</enforcePropertyRestrictions>
        <persistenceXmlFile>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml</persistenceXmlFile>
        <classes>${project.build.outputDirectory}</classes>
        <workDir>${project.build.directory}\openjpa-work</workDir>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>enhancer</id>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>enhance</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
            <artifactId>openjpa</artifactId>
            <version>${openjpa.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>

Hope it helps someone !!
```